# 2D Array - counting number sequence

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, matrix

I am somehow completely on the hose. It is to be understood by the functional principle and does not sound particularly difficult? But i can not really come up with a possible solution.

I have a 2D array. It is 8x8. Each field can include number between 1-7. Now i want to "return" per / row in the vertical/horizontal the numbers, which are at least 3x in a row behind each other or with each other. Thus theoretically pro / series there is the possibility that two sequences of numbers are possible.

**Now the real question:** HOW can I just return the numbers that are at least 3x in a row in width/height!? Happy with index. I have now tried a lot, neither with iteration nor recursion. But i came to the desired result - or i do not see the forest for the trees ...?

Example:

[image: output]

Comment: _"Now i want to "return" per / row in the vertical/horizontal the numbers, which are at least 3x in a row behind each other or with each other."_ huh? You want to find runs of the same number in a row (or at least length 3)? What _exactly_ do you expect as a result?

Comment: _"HOW can I just return the numbers that are at least 3x in a row in width/height!? Happy with index. I have now tried a lot, neither with iteration nor recursion. But i came to the desired result "_ include you best attempt (actual code) in the question. It's really hard to figure out exactly what you are looking for. And are you starting with an int[,] or int[][]?

Comment: *"I have now tried a lot, neither with iteration nor recursion"* - we need your code to help with fixing it. Basically, you can just do it with 2 loops. Two loops `i` and `j` from 1 to n-1 and check if `a[i][j-1] == a[i][j] == a[i][j+1]` and `a[i-1][j] == a[i][j] == a[i+1][j]`, and that's done.

Comment: And have you attempted this for a 1D array? If you can figure it out for a 1D array, then all you need to do is wrap that in another loop for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this for a 1d array first.

We have an array with 8 numbers.

```
public List<int> Get3InRow(int[] array)
    {
        List<int> found = new List<int>(); // the list of found numbers we return
        int counter = 1;  //counts the amount of identical numbers found.
        int number = array[0];  //the number we are counting.

        //now comes the for loop
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == number) counter++; // if we find a match counter goes up
            else
            {  //else reset the counter and search for new number.
                number = array[i];
                counter = 1;
            }
            if (counter == 3) found.Add(array[i]); // if we find 3 matching numbers ad it to the found list
        }
        return found;
    }
```

now to do this with a 2d array. All we have to do is add another for loop.

```
public List<int> Get3InRow(int[,] array)
    {
        List<int> found = new List<int>(); // the list of found numbers we return
        int counter = 1;  //counts the amount of identical numbers found.
        int number = 9;  //the number we are counting. (we chose 9 because none of the numbers in the array have this number.)

        //now comes the for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {                    
                if (array[i,j] == number) counter++; // if we find a match counter goes up
                else
                {  //else reset the counter and search for new number.
                    number = array[i,j];
                    counter = 1;
                }
                if (counter == 3) found.Add(array[i,j]); // if we find 3 matching numbers ad it to the found list
            }
        }

        //we repeat the for loops with i and j interchanged(in array[]) because now we want to check the other axis
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if (array[j,i] == number) counter++; // if we find a match counter goes up
                else
                {  //else reset the counter and search for new number.
                    number = array[j,i];
                    counter = 1;
                }
                if (counter == 3) found.Add(array[j,i]); // if we find 3 matching numbers ad it to the found list
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, i'll found a solution.

```
private static List<List<Point>> Test(int[][] Matrix, Point Position, List<List<Point>> Pos) {
  if (Position.Y < Matrix.Length && Position.X < Matrix[Position.Y].Length) {
    if (Similar(Matrix, new Point(Position.X, Position.Y), new Point(Position.X + 1, Position.Y))) {
      List<Point> List = Pos.LastOrDefault();
      if (List == null) List = new List<Point>();

      List.Add(new Point(Position.X, Position.Y));
      List.Add(new Point(Position.X + 1, Position.Y));

      Pos.Remove(Pos.LastOrDefault());
      Pos.Add(List.Distinct().ToList());
    } else Pos.Add(new List<Point>());

    return Test(Matrix, new Point(Position.X + 1, Position.Y), Pos);
  } else {
    if (Position.Y < Matrix.Length && Position.X == Matrix[Position.Y].Length)
      return Test(Matrix, new Point(0, Position.Y + 1), Pos);
  }

  return Pos.Where(Entity => Entity.Count > 0).ToList();
}
```